# Pathfinding - A* with weight map and least turn

Tags: python, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I am currently trying to implement A* path-finding from [this GitHub](https://gist.github.com/ryancollingwood/32446307e976a11a1185a5394d6657bc) with 2 things:

- A **weight map**, I try to force the algorithm to stay in the middle of the path. It still has to take the shortest path, but it need to stay on the main "road". Here is an example map:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0
0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 3 3 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Every **0** is a wall and other nodes take the distance to the closest wall.
I want the algorithm to stay on the highest number while taking the shortest path, on this map the optimal path between (1, 1) and (18, 18) would be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 | 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 | 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 | 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 └ ┐ 1 1 1 1 2 1 0
0 1 | 2 2 2 2 2 1 0
0 1 └ - - - - ┐ 1 0
0 1 2 2 2 2 2 └ ┐ 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 | 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I can achieve this by adding the `max_node_weight - current_node_weight` to **G** (distance between the current node and the start node) but when I use this algorithm on bigger maps (I need 300 by 300) it can take more than 1 hour because it check too many nodes.

It's because **H** (estimated distance from the current node to the end node) is too small at every node and **G** become too big in the end so the algorithm choose to check node where **G** is smaller. I tried to weight **H** but without great success.

- With **least turn**, I have seen some implementation of it, but I don't really see how I can implement it with the weight map. I don't want to have strange case where the algorithm does this:

```
3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3         3 3 3 ┌ - - - ┐ 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3         - - - ┘ 3 3 3 └ - - -
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2         2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Instead of this:

```
3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3
- - - - - - - - - - -
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I don't know if A* is adapted for this, I don't know if something like this already exist but I found nothing.

Any idea on how I could do this ? :)

**Edit:**

Here is what I am trying right now:

I use the max weight to apply a ratio to **H**:

```
heuristic_ratio = ((max_node_weight**2) / 1.5)**2
H = (abs(child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) + abs(child.position[1] - end_node.position[1])) * heuristic_ratio
```

I also use this ratio on **G** if I have a turn, I also amplify the differences between to path with different weight:

```
turn_weight = 0
if turn:
  turn_weight = heuristic_ratio
G = parent.g + turn_weight + (max_node_weight**2 - current_node_weight**2)**2
```

It works most of the time but I still have time where the algorithm hug the wall while being in the middle do not change the number of move:

```
this:
 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 
 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ┌ - - - - - - - - 0 
 - - ┐ 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 
 4 3 | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 
 4 3 | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 
 4 3 | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 
 5 4 └ - - - - - - - ┘ 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1 0

instead of this:
 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 
 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 ┌ - - - - 0 
 ┐ 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 | 4 3 2 1 0 
 | 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 | 4 3 2 1 0 
 | 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 | 4 3 2 1 0 
 | 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 | 4 3 2 1 0 
 └ - - - - - - - - - - - - - ┘ 4 3 2 1 0
```

I don't know ho to fix this.

Comment: It sound like in your implementation that `G` is  preferably a large value, while `H` is preferably a small value. Maybe trying to invert the values, meaning that the largest value become 1 and 1 becomes the largest value, and go for low `F`-values (`G`+`H`). The walls in this case would be infinity

Comment: It is already what I do: ```G = max_node_weight - current_node_weight + parent_G``` I take the max value in the map and subtract the current value

Comment: How about calculating `H` as the manhattan distance instead of the euclidian as the github does. `H` then becomes ```abs(child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) + abs(child.position[1] - end_node.position[1])``` as you cannot travel diagonally

Comment: I already do this too, I forgot to mention it. I have edited my post to show how I compute **G** and **H**. Just the Manhattan distance was not enough so I tried to apply a ratio to it, I am not sure on how to compute a relevant ratio.